# Spotify app crashes with no crash log

Tags: iphone, spotify, sigabrt, cocoalibspotify-2.0

[image: Xcode screenshot]

I'm working with cocoalibspotify. My app is about finished but I'm stuck with some weird issue. When I try to login again after logging out, the app crashes leaving with no crash log and **later on** my debug point goes to the line

```
sp_session_logout(outgoing_session);
```

from the method `-(void)logout:(void (^)())completionBlock` in class `SPSession.m`

And beside it there is `signal SIGABRT`.

Check out the screenshot I've attached. which shows the crash point with no crash log below in console.

This crash happens only `happens sometimes` rather than every time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you waiting for the completion block on your `logout:` call to fire before logging back in again? That'll cause problems, and the `logout:` call can take a while to complete at times.

In addition, does this problem occur with the latest `master` release, 2.4.0? How about the `HEAD` of the `dev` branch?

Comment: hi daniel! No, I'm not using the latest cocoalibspotify 2.4.0. Before that where you've identified version in your sample examples? Moreover, I'm using // logout from app
    [[SPSession sharedSession] logout:^{
    }]

Comment: I'm using // logout from app
    [[SPSession sharedSession] logout:^{
    }]  for logging out from the spotify. SO, I guess I'm not waiting for the completion block.

Comment: Versions are applied as tags on the master branch. See https://github.com/spotify/cocoalibspotify/tags and https://github.com/spotify/cocoalibspotify/blob/master/CHANGELOG.markdown

Comment: yes, daniel that I know , but how one can come to know from the sample examples that on which version he/she is working?

Comment: lets say I'm running simple player. Then how can I come to know that which version this app is using. Is it mentioned in some .h file or in some read me text?

Comment: Run `git describe` on the repo or look at the CHANGELOG.markdown file.

Comment: ok.got it. & let me also congratulate you for the 2.4.0. good!

Comment: in my app I do not wait for the logout then why my app gets crash at this point? did you check screenshot?

Comment: I did. Did you try anything I suggested in my answer?

Comment: no. At this stage I can't change the version of the cocoalibspotify since my app is about to finish. So can you suggest me something to do with current version only.& what to mean by HEAD of the dev branch?

Comment: I mean checking out the newest commit in the `dev` branch. I did suggest something — making sure you wait for the logout callback to complete before attempting to log in again. Other than that, there's nothing I can suggest apart from updating.

Comment: [[SPSession sharedSession] logout:^{ }]  - that's an empty completion block right there. or maybe you stripped your code out in the comment?